# Angular ng toolkit universal not loading , tools not working

Tags: angular, npm

I get the following error

```
npm run build: prod
```

commands do not work

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ERROR: If you think
>   that this error shouldn't occur, please fill up bug report here:
>   https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/new INFO: stacktrace
>   has been sent to tracking system. npm WARN @angular/animations@7.2.12
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.12 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@7.2.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/animations@7.2.14 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/platform-server@7.2.14
>   requires a peer of @angular/common@7.2.14 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@7.2.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/compiler@7.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/platform-server@7.2.14
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.14 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@7.2.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/http@7.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/platform-server@7.2.14
>   requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@7.2.14 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@7.2.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.2.14 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed.
>   You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 0):

Have you done: *npm install* command to download and install all modules and dependencies?